# stored procedure logic,data flow visualization tool

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have a very poorly written stored procedure with cursors, if else etc. Is there any toll available to visualise the logic and data flow?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've used a program called [Code Visual to Flowchart](http://www.fatesoft.com/s2f/), if you feed in a SQL file it will generate a flowchart based on it. The free version is all I've used and it met the needs I had, making it much easier to work my way through a 3000 line procedure that was completely devoid of comments.

"I can confirm I have no affiliation to this product"

Comment: Is the program free or paid? Is it open or closed source?

Comment: Closed. There is a free version and a paid version. The last time I was using it the differences were that the free version had some limitations like being able to print/save the diagrams.